# How to move a component or create a copy of it

Tags: javascript, angular

I already have an input component, I do not want to create another for editing, I want to use the same one.
How to replace a block with a task (`<li>`) with an input component for further editing when you click on the edit button?

[link to git repo](https://github.com/studentota2lvl/Angular-todo)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code?

Comment: @ Matt U https://github.com/studentota2lvl/Angular-todo    i have no idea. For example, I can hide the upper input, but in any case, I do not know how to move it to the editing location

Answer (score 0):

No need to create or copy almost similar component until there is big changes in functionality or requirement.

You can simply toggle the view conditionally, On click of button show Edit's view else keep showing list part.

PS: Use `*ngIf` or `hidden`

Comment: I also think so, but how to move the input component to the block of editing, or replace it?

Comment: Yes. I attach a link to the repo in the start message